# What does this error mean: "resolver::resolvePath..."?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send a variable value from my main HTML to the iframe inside, but I get this error every time iFrame is loaded:

`resolver::resolvePath - Path did not resolve at: confedenceVar`

iFrame itself loads properly but `confedenceVar` which is a variable inside the iFrame's JS file generates that error. 
What's that error mean? There is not much about it on the net...

Comment: That doesn't look like a JavaScript error -- JavaScript doesn't use `::` in function names.

Comment: It's probably coming from the application you're loading in the iframe.